# About logic conjunction - if A & B = C, how to get A from B, C?

Tags: expression

Let us say A & B = C

How can I get A from B and C?

For example, 1 & 0 = 0 and 0 & 0 = 0. In this case B and C are both 0 but A is different.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1):

Only XOR and NOT are capable of recovering the original values. All other boolean operators lose information and and can't recover the original values.